# Browsing context has been discarded when running Protractor tests against firefox in selenium grid

Tags: protractor, e2e-testing, geckodriver

I am trying to run my e2e Protractor tests again Selenium Grid - Firefox, but keep running into this error for "Browsing context has been discarded".

Example of the stack trace is:

```
 × should have expected page elements #Smoke
        - Failed: Browsing context has been discarded
            at Object.throwDecodedError (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:514:15)
            at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:519:13)
            at doSend.then.response (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30)
            at <anonymous>
            at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
        From: Task: Protractor.waitForAngular() - Locator: By(css selector, select[formControlName="pageType"])
            at thenableWebDriverProxy.schedule (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:807:17)
            at ProtractorBrowser.executeAsyncScript_ (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\browser.js:425:28)
            at angularAppRoot.then (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\browser.js:456:33)
            at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1376:14)
            at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3084:14)
            at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3067:27)
            at asyncRun (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2927:27)
            at C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:668:7
            at <anonymous>
            at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
        From: Task: <anonymous>
```

The weird part of this, is that if I change one bit of my test code, it will pass. Here is a sample of the test

```
import Base from "../../common-pages/base.po";

describe('Edit Page', function () {

    let pageName = "AutoQA Page " + base.now();

    beforeAll(function (done) {
        login = new Login();
        login.login(login.userAdmin, login.password);

        pages = new Pages();

        let newPage = {
            'pageName': pageName,
            'pageKey': pageKey
        };

        pages.sendApiRequest('POST', pages.pagesEndpoint, newPage, 200);
        done();
    });

    beforeEach(function (done) {
        pages.goto(pages.url);

        pages.searchPages(pageName);
        pages.getFirstRecordInTable().click(); // this seems to be where context is discarded

        form = new PageForm();
        appliedPageType = form.getElementText(form.pageTypeField);
        done();
    });

    it('test case #Smoke', function (done) {
        // removed test code because it doesn't make it here
        done();
    });
});
```

The code above does not work, but if I simply change this bit `pages.searchPages(pageName);` to some existing data on the page like `pages.searchPages("Existing Page A");`, it reaches the test code as expected...

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Have already tried things such as forcing geckoversion to 20.0 (something I've seen on s/o for this issue already but did not work)

Here are my related versions in case:
selenium: 3.141.59
geckodriver: v0.24.0
protractor: 5.4.1
node: 8.11.4

Here is the debug log from geckodriver:

```
1558383055692   Marionette  DEBUG   0 <- [1,120,null,[{"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"9c8208bb-e666-484e-b565-716b11d93a08"},{"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466 ... ecf":"5249171e-cbe6-4594-b06a-aac99ae6c777"},{"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"81bae4a4-f023-4a12-9348-8ba6169b5e60"}]]
1558383055692   webdriver::server   DEBUG   <- 200 OK {"value":[{"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"9c8208bb-e666-484e-b565-716b11d93a08"},{"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"0b6b9bcf-5247-4f70-ad1e-b7eadbaa5d4a"},{"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"d3a89d8b-54a2-4e15-a4fe-29ebae88905a"},{"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"5249171e-cbe6-4594-b06a-aac99ae6c777"},{"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"81bae4a4-f023-4a12-9348-8ba6169b5e60"}]}
1558383055705   webdriver::server   DEBUG   -> GET /session/db6b42c4-ef8d-485f-9aca-4b4951924089/element/9c8208bb-e666-484e-b565-716b11d93a08/text 
1558383055706   Marionette  DEBUG   0 -> [0,121,"WebDriver:GetElementText",{"id":"9c8208bb-e666-484e-b565-716b11d93a08"}]
1558383055711   Marionette  DEBUG   0 <- [1,121,null,{"value":"AutoQA Page 1558383045962"}]
1558383055712   webdriver::server   DEBUG   <- 200 OK {"value":"AutoQA Page 1558383045962"}
1558383055723   webdriver::server   DEBUG   -> POST /session/db6b42c4-ef8d-485f-9aca-4b4951924089/execute/async {"script":"try { return (function anonymous() {\nfunction getNg1Hooks(selector, injectorPlease) {\n  function tryEl(el) {\n    try {\n      if (!injectorPlease && angular.getTestability) {\n        var $$testability = angular.getTestability(el);\n        if ($$testability) {\n          return {$$testability: $$testability};\n        }\n      } else {\n        var $injector = angular.element(el).injector();\n        if ($injector) {\n          return {$injector: $injector};\n        }\n      }\n    } catch(err) {}\n  }\n  function trySelector(selector) {\n    var els = document.querySelectorAll(selector);\n    for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {\n      var elHooks = tryEl(els[i]);\n      if (elHooks) {\n        return elHooks;\n      }\n    }\n  }\n\n  if (selector) {\n    return trySelector(selector);\n  } else if (window.__TESTABILITY__NG1_APP_ROOT_INJECTOR__) {\n    var $injector = window.__TESTABILITY__NG1_APP_ROOT_INJECTOR__;\n    var $$testability = null;\n    try {\n      $$testability = $injector.get('$$testability');\n    } catch (e) {}\n    return {$injector: $injector, $$testability: $$testability};\n  } else {\n    return tryEl(document.body) ||\n        trySelector('[ng-app]') || trySelector('[ng\\\\:app]') ||\n        trySelector('[ng-controller]') || trySelector('[ng\\\\:controller]');\n  }\n};  return (function (rootSelector, callback) {\n\n  try {\n    // Wait for both angular1 testability and angular2 testability.\n\n    var testCallback = callback;\n\n    // Wait for angular1 testability first and run waitForAngular2 as a callback\n    var waitForAngular1 = function(callback) {\n\n      if (window.angular) {\n        var hooks = getNg1Hooks(rootSelector);\n        if (!hooks){\n          callback();  // not an angular1 app\n        }\n        else{\n          if (hooks.$$testability) {\n            hooks.$$testability.whenStable(callback);\n          } else if (hooks.$injector) {\n            hooks.$injector.get('$browser')\n                .notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests(callback);\n          } else if (!rootSelector) {\n            throw new Error(\n                'Could not automatically find injector on page: \"' +\n                window.location.toString() + '\".  Consider using config.rootEl');\n          } else {\n            throw new Error(\n                'root element (' + rootSelector + ') has no injector.' +\n                ' this may mean it is not inside ng-app.');\n          }\n        }\n      }\n      else {callback();}  // not an angular1 app\n    };\n\n    // Wait for Angular2 testability and then run test callback\n    var waitForAngular2 = function() {\n      if (window.getAngularTestability) {\n        if (rootSelector) {\n          var testability = null;\n          var el = document.querySelector(rootSelector);\n          try{\n            testability = window.getAngularTestability(el);\n          }\n          catch(e){}\n          if (testability) {\n            testability.whenStable(testCallback);\n            return;\n          }\n        }\n\n        // Didn't specify root element or testability could not be found\n        // by rootSelector. This may happen in a hybrid app, which could have\n        // more than one root.\n        var testabilities = window.getAllAngularTestabilities();\n        var count = testabilities.length;\n\n        // No angular2 testability, this happens when\n        // going to a hybrid page and going back to a pure angular1 page\n        if (count === 0) {\n          testCallback();\n          return;\n        }\n\n        var decrement = function() {\n          count--;\n          if (count === 0) {\n            testCallback();\n          }\n        };\n        testabilities.forEach(function(testability) {\n          testability.whenStable(decrement);\n        });\n\n      }\n      else {testCallback();}  // not an angular2 app\n    };\n\n    if (!(window.angular) && !(window.getAngularTestability)) {\n      // no testability hook\n      throw new Error(\n          'both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.' +\n          '  This could be either ' +\n          'because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves ' +\n          'client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor\\'s ' +\n          'bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details');\n    } else {waitForAngular1(waitForAngular2);}  // Wait for angular1 and angular2\n                                                // Testability hooks sequentially\n\n  } catch (err) {\n    callback(err.message);\n  }\n\n}).apply(this, arguments);\n}).apply(this, arguments); }\ncatch(e) { throw (e instanceof Error) ? e : new Error(e); }","args":[""]}
1558383055725   Marionette  DEBUG   0 -> [0,122,"WebDriver:ExecuteAsyncScript",{"args":[""],"script":"try { return (function anonymous() {\nfunction getNg1Hooks(selec ... }\n\n}).apply(this, arguments);\n}).apply(this, arguments); }\ncatch(e) { throw (e instanceof Error) ? e : new Error(e); }"}]
1558383055728   Marionette  DEBUG   0 <- [1,122,null,{"value":null}]
1558383055728   webdriver::server   DEBUG   <- 200 OK {"value":null}
1558383055738   webdriver::server   DEBUG   -> POST /session/db6b42c4-ef8d-485f-9aca-4b4951924089/elements {"using":"css selector","value":".table-striped"}
1558383055739   Marionette  DEBUG   0 -> [0,123,"WebDriver:FindElements",{"using":"css selector","value":".table-striped"}]
1558383055741   Marionette  DEBUG   0 <- [1,123,null,[{"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"9b283ce7-4e06-46a4-ab94-776e4e52def8"}]]
1558383055742   webdriver::server   DEBUG   <- 200 OK {"value":[{"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"9b283ce7-4e06-46a4-ab94-776e4e52def8"}]}
1558383055752   webdriver::server   DEBUG   -> POST /session/db6b42c4-ef8d-485f-9aca-4b4951924089/element/9b283ce7-4e06-46a4-ab94-776e4e52def8/elements {"using":"css selector","value":"tbody > tr.d-flex > td"}
1558383055753   Marionette  DEBUG   0 -> [0,124,"WebDriver:FindElements",{"element":"9b283ce7-4e06-46a4-ab94-776e4e52def8","using":"css selector","value":"tbody > tr.d-flex > td"}]
1558383055755   Marionette  DEBUG   0 <- [1,124,null,[{"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"9c8208bb-e666-484e-b565-716b11d93a08"},{"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466 ... ecf":"5249171e-cbe6-4594-b06a-aac99ae6c777"},{"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"81bae4a4-f023-4a12-9348-8ba6169b5e60"}]]
1558383055756   webdriver::server   DEBUG   <- 200 OK {"value":[{"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"9c8208bb-e666-484e-b565-716b11d93a08"},{"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"0b6b9bcf-5247-4f70-ad1e-b7eadbaa5d4a"},{"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"d3a89d8b-54a2-4e15-a4fe-29ebae88905a"},{"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"5249171e-cbe6-4594-b06a-aac99ae6c777"},{"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"81bae4a4-f023-4a12-9348-8ba6169b5e60"}]}
1558383055771   webdriver::server   DEBUG   -> POST /session/db6b42c4-ef8d-485f-9aca-4b4951924089/element/9c8208bb-e666-484e-b565-716b11d93a08/click {}
1558383055812   Marionette  DEBUG   0 -> [0,125,"WebDriver:ElementClick",{"id":"9c8208bb-e666-484e-b565-716b11d93a08"}]
[Parent 79, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error (76): Connection reset by peer: file /builds/worker/workspace/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 349
2019-05-20T20:10:56.191328300Z 
###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x1E0086,name=PBrowser::Msg_Destroy) Channel error: cannot send/recv
2019-05-20T20:10:56.191359600Z 
1558383056220   Marionette  TRACE   [19] Frame script loaded
1558383056220   Marionette  TRACE   [19] Frame script registered
A content process crashed and MOZ_CRASHREPORTER_SHUTDOWN is set, shutting down
1558383056259   Marionette  TRACE   [19] Check readyState uninitialized for about:blank
1558383056292   Marionette  TRACE   Received DOM event unload for [object XULDocument]
1558383056300   Marionette  TRACE   Received observer notification message-manager-disconnect
1558383056303   Marionette  DEBUG   0 <- [1,125,null,{"value":null}]
1558383056311   webdriver::server   DEBUG   <- 200 OK {"value":null}
1558383056324   webdriver::server   DEBUG   -> POST /session/db6b42c4-ef8d-485f-9aca-4b4951924089/execute/async {"script":"try { return (function anonymous() {\nfunction getNg1Hooks(selector, injectorPlease) {\n  function tryEl(el) {\n    try {\n      if (!injectorPlease && angular.getTestability) {\n        var $$testability = angular.getTestability(el);\n        if ($$testability) {\n          return {$$testability: $$testability};\n        }\n      } else {\n        var $injector = angular.element(el).injector();\n        if ($injector) {\n          return {$injector: $injector};\n        }\n      }\n    } catch(err) {}\n  }\n  function trySelector(selector) {\n    var els = document.querySelectorAll(selector);\n    for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {\n      var elHooks = tryEl(els[i]);\n      if (elHooks) {\n        return elHooks;\n      }\n    }\n  }\n\n  if (selector) {\n    return trySelector(selector);\n  } else if (window.__TESTABILITY__NG1_APP_ROOT_INJECTOR__) {\n    var $injector = window.__TESTABILITY__NG1_APP_ROOT_INJECTOR__;\n    var $$testability = null;\n    try {\n      $$testability = $injector.get('$$testability');\n    } catch (e) {}\n    return {$injector: $injector, $$testability: $$testability};\n  } else {\n    return tryEl(document.body) ||\n        trySelector('[ng-app]') || trySelector('[ng\\\\:app]') ||\n        trySelector('[ng-controller]') || trySelector('[ng\\\\:controller]');\n  }\n};  return (function (rootSelector, callback) {\n\n  try {\n    // Wait for both angular1 testability and angular2 testability.\n\n    var testCallback = callback;\n\n    // Wait for angular1 testability first and run waitForAngular2 as a callback\n    var waitForAngular1 = function(callback) {\n\n      if (window.angular) {\n        var hooks = getNg1Hooks(rootSelector);\n        if (!hooks){\n          callback();  // not an angular1 app\n        }\n        else{\n          if (hooks.$$testability) {\n            hooks.$$testability.whenStable(callback);\n          } else if (hooks.$injector) {\n            hooks.$injector.get('$browser')\n                .notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests(callback);\n          } else if (!rootSelector) {\n            throw new Error(\n                'Could not automatically find injector on page: \"' +\n                window.location.toString() + '\".  Consider using config.rootEl');\n          } else {\n            throw new Error(\n                'root element (' + rootSelector + ') has no injector.' +\n                ' this may mean it is not inside ng-app.');\n          }\n        }\n      }\n      else {callback();}  // not an angular1 app\n    };\n\n    // Wait for Angular2 testability and then run test callback\n    var waitForAngular2 = function() {\n      if (window.getAngularTestability) {\n        if (rootSelector) {\n          var testability = null;\n          var el = document.querySelector(rootSelector);\n          try{\n            testability = window.getAngularTestability(el);\n          }\n          catch(e){}\n          if (testability) {\n            testability.whenStable(testCallback);\n            return;\n          }\n        }\n\n        // Didn't specify root element or testability could not be found\n        // by rootSelector. This may happen in a hybrid app, which could have\n        // more than one root.\n        var testabilities = window.getAllAngularTestabilities();\n        var count = testabilities.length;\n\n        // No angular2 testability, this happens when\n        // going to a hybrid page and going back to a pure angular1 page\n        if (count === 0) {\n          testCallback();\n          return;\n        }\n\n        var decrement = function() {\n          count--;\n          if (count === 0) {\n            testCallback();\n          }\n        };\n        testabilities.forEach(function(testability) {\n          testability.whenStable(decrement);\n        });\n\n      }\n      else {testCallback();}  // not an angular2 app\n    };\n\n    if (!(window.angular) && !(window.getAngularTestability)) {\n      // no testability hook\n      throw new Error(\n          'both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.' +\n          '  This could be either ' +\n          'because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves ' +\n          'client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor\\'s ' +\n          'bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details');\n    } else {waitForAngular1(waitForAngular2);}  // Wait for angular1 and angular2\n                                                // Testability hooks sequentially\n\n  } catch (err) {\n    callback(err.message);\n  }\n\n}).apply(this, arguments);\n}).apply(this, arguments); }\ncatch(e) { throw (e instanceof Error) ? e : new Error(e); }","args":[""]}
1558383056326   Marionette  DEBUG   0 -> [0,126,"WebDriver:ExecuteAsyncScript",{"args":[""],"script":"try { return (function anonymous() {\nfunction getNg1Hooks(selec ... }\n\n}).apply(this, arguments);\n}).apply(this, arguments); }\ncatch(e) { throw (e instanceof Error) ? e : new Error(e); }"}]
1558383056327   Marionette  DEBUG   0 <- [1,126,{"error":"no such window","message":"Browsing context has been discarded","stacktrace":"WebDriverError@chrome://marion ... et@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:236:8\n_onJSONObjectReady/<@chrome://marionette/content/transport.js:490:9\n"},null]
1558383056331   webdriver::server   DEBUG   <- 404 Not Found {"value":{"error":"no such window","message":"Browsing context has been discarded","stacktrace":"WebDriverError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:179:5\nNoSuchWindowError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:411:5\nassert.that/<@chrome://marionette/content/assert.js:418:13\nassert.open@chrome://marionette/content/assert.js:174:10\nGeckoDriver.prototype.execute_@chrome://marionette/content/driver.js:994:3\nGeckoDriver.prototype.executeAsyncScript@chrome://marionette/content/driver.js:975:24\ndespatch@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:291:20\nexecute@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:264:11\nonPacket/<@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:237:15\nonPacket@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:236:8\n_onJSONObjectReady/<@chrome://marionette/content/transport.js:490:9\n"}}
1558383056371   webdriver::server   DEBUG   -> POST /session/db6b42c4-ef8d-485f-9aca-4b4951924089/execute/async {"script":"try { return (function anonymous() {\nfunction getNg1Hooks(selector, injectorPlease) {\n  function tryEl(el) {\n    try {\n      if (!injectorPlease && angular.getTestability) {\n        var $$testability = angular.getTestability(el);\n        if ($$testability) {\n          return {$$testability: $$testability};\n        }\n      } else {\n        var $injector = angular.element(el).injector();\n        if ($injector) {\n          return {$injector: $injector};\n        }\n      }\n    } catch(err) {}\n  }\n  function trySelector(selector) {\n    var els = document.querySelectorAll(selector);\n    for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {\n      var elHooks = tryEl(els[i]);\n      if (elHooks) {\n        return elHooks;\n      }\n    }\n  }\n\n  if (selector) {\n    return trySelector(selector);\n  } else if (window.__TESTABILITY__NG1_APP_ROOT_INJECTOR__) {\n    var $injector = window.__TESTABILITY__NG1_APP_ROOT_INJECTOR__;\n    var $$testability = null;\n    try {\n      $$testability = $injector.get('$$testability');\n    } catch (e) {}\n    return {$injector: $injector, $$testability: $$testability};\n  } else {\n    return tryEl(document.body) ||\n        trySelector('[ng-app]') || trySelector('[ng\\\\:app]') ||\n        trySelector('[ng-controller]') || trySelector('[ng\\\\:controller]');\n  }\n};  return (function (rootSelector, callback) {\n\n  try {\n    // Wait for both angular1 testability and angular2 testability.\n\n    var testCallback = callback;\n\n    // Wait for angular1 testability first and run waitForAngular2 as a callback\n    var waitForAngular1 = function(callback) {\n\n      if (window.angular) {\n        var hooks = getNg1Hooks(rootSelector);\n        if (!hooks){\n          callback();  // not an angular1 app\n        }\n        else{\n          if (hooks.$$testability) {\n            hooks.$$testability.whenStable(callback);\n          } else if (hooks.$injector) {\n            hooks.$injector.get('$browser')\n                .notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests(callback);\n          } else if (!rootSelector) {\n            throw new Error(\n                'Could not automatically find injector on page: \"' +\n                window.location.toString() + '\".  Consider using config.rootEl');\n          } else {\n            throw new Error(\n                'root element (' + rootSelector + ') has no injector.' +\n                ' this may mean it is not inside ng-app.');\n          }\n        }\n      }\n      else {callback();}  // not an angular1 app\n    };\n\n    // Wait for Angular2 testability and then run test callback\n    var waitForAngular2 = function() {\n      if (window.getAngularTestability) {\n        if (rootSelector) {\n          var testability = null;\n          var el = document.querySelector(rootSelector);\n          try{\n            testability = window.getAngularTestability(el);\n          }\n          catch(e){}\n          if (testability) {\n            testability.whenStable(testCallback);\n            return;\n          }\n        }\n\n        // Didn't specify root element or testability could not be found\n        // by rootSelector. This may happen in a hybrid app, which could have\n        // more than one root.\n        var testabilities = window.getAllAngularTestabilities();\n        var count = testabilities.length;\n\n        // No angular2 testability, this happens when\n        // going to a hybrid page and going back to a pure angular1 page\n        if (count === 0) {\n          testCallback();\n          return;\n        }\n\n        var decrement = function() {\n          count--;\n          if (count === 0) {\n            testCallback();\n          }\n        };\n        testabilities.forEach(function(testability) {\n          testability.whenStable(decrement);\n        });\n\n      }\n      else {testCallback();}  // not an angular2 app\n    };\n\n    if (!(window.angular) && !(window.getAngularTestability)) {\n      // no testability hook\n      throw new Error(\n          'both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.' +\n          '  This could be either ' +\n          'because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves ' +\n          'client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor\\'s ' +\n          'bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details');\n    } else {waitForAngular1(waitForAngular2);}  // Wait for angular1 and angular2\n                                                // Testability hooks sequentially\n\n  } catch (err) {\n    callback(err.message);\n  }\n\n}).apply(this, arguments);\n}).apply(this, arguments); }\ncatch(e) { throw (e instanceof Error) ? e : new Error(e); }","args":[""]}
1558383056375   webdriver::server   DEBUG   Deleting session
```

Comment: Could you tell us where `pageName` is declared? I don't see it in your spec file

Comment: Sure, I just edit original post with that. If I change that variable to simple string like "test" even it still gives the same error.

Comment: Sorry I may be confused, could you confirm the behavior when you set `pages.searchPages("Existing Page A")` and is that same as when you set it to  `pages.searchPages("test")`. Does the test pass with these hardcoded strings?

Comment: Yes exactly, the hard coded strings with existing data pass each time. But whatever I have set in `pageName` ends up giving this error.

Comment: Do you know if you insert a `console.log(pageName)` before the `pages.searchPages(pageName);` would it log anything?

Comment: Yes, it does log the expected pageName value.